DAZ Iray section planes for Blender?
DAZ has a feature called Iray Section Planes, that lets you hide geometry from the renderer in order to speed up the rendering process.
It also lets you keep any light emitted by that geometry, so when you render parts of a scene with hidden geometry, the lighting will not change.
For example, part of a rooms ceiling is emitting light, and you can hide parts of the ceiling without changing the overall lighting of the scene.
Does Blender (or maybe an add-on) offer this functionality?
Thanks!

That kind of thing would depend on the render engine.
With Cycles, I think disabling the Camera ray visibility would do the trick
This can be done either in the object's settings, or in the shader nodes, depending on if you want to filter out a whole object or only parts of if that have a specific material - or multiple objects that share the same material:



Per object wouldn't work well, if there is an entire room with maybe dozens of individual objects, and most of them off camera for a particular shot. With DAZ, you place a plane behind the camera for example, and all that geometry behind the plane will be invisible to the Iray engine. Except any lights emitted from that area. This can drop render times easily by 80% depending on the shot.

Clearly neither Cycles nor Eevee have a specific feature like Iray's, but perhaps we can achieve a similar result using the above. I don't think it would matter much for Eevee since raster engines do not calculate anything that is out of screen. As for Cycles, perhaps we can get similar result using the above shader. Maybe even a Holdout shader node would work better than a Transparent. But the idea is there: use the Light Path node to "filter out" what to let pass through the plane or not.
